# Advanced Custom Fields doesnt shows the Text on Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've been trying to solve the problem for weeks but without any solution...

I have installed the Plugin Advanced Custom Field and insert the Text. On the Elementor Edit i have chosen the created Field. But in the context it doesn't show the word

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9fwz.jpg)

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same bug.
All I did was delete the broken ACF field in the Custom Field and recreated it. Don't know where did the bug comes from but it's now solved.

Make sure you link your ACF field back into your Elementor widget.

Cheers,

Chris